# Question about $z=-e^{\ln(n)\cdot(-x-2)+\ln(m)\cdot(x-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation, real-numbers

If we know that (where all the variables are real and positive):

$$z=-e^{\ln(n)\cdot(-x-2)+\ln(m)\cdot(x-1)}$$

What will this be:

$$e^{\ln(n)\cdot(-x-2)+\ln(m)\cdot(x+1)}$$

in terms of $z$?

---

My work:

I can write:

$$z=-e^{\ln(n)\cdot(-x-2)+\ln(m)\cdot(x-1)}=-e^{\ln(n)\cdot(-x-2)}\cdot e^{\ln(m)\cdot(x-1)}$$

And then I do not now how to proceed.

Comment: Hint for how to keep going from where you left off: $e^{a\ln b}=(e^{\ln b})^a=b^a$.

Comment: To answer the question you **asked**, "How to write $e^{ln(n)(-x-2)+ ln(m)(x-1)}$ in terms of z", just multiply by -1! $z= -e^{ln(n)(-x-2)+ ln(m)(x-1)}$.  You don't have to proceed unless you are trying to do something else.  But what are you really asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $e^{x \ln a} = e^{\ln a^{x}} = a^{x}$ then
$$-z = e^{-(x+2) \ln(n) + (x-1) \ln m} = \frac{1}{m \, n^{2}} \, \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{x}.$$
Now
\begin{align}
e^{-(x+2) \ln(n) + (x+1) \ln m} &= \frac{m}{n^{2}} \, \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{x} \\
&= m^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{m \, n^{2}} \, \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{x} \\
&= - m^{2} \, z. 
\end{align}

This can also be seen as:
\begin{align}
e^{-(x+2) \ln(n) + (x+1) \ln m} &= e^{-(x+2) \ln(n) + (x-1) \ln m + 2 \ln m} \\
&= m^{2} \, e^{-(x+2) \ln(n) + (x-1) \ln m} \\
&= - m^{2} \, z 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Call:

$$g=e^{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\cdot\left(-x-2\right)+\ln\left(\text{m}\right)\cdot\left(x+1\right)}$$

and calculate:

$$\frac{g}{z}=-\frac{e^{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\cdot\left(-x-2\right)+\ln\left(\text{m}\right)\cdot\left(x-1\right)}}{e^{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\cdot\left(-x-2\right)+\ln\left(\text{m}\right)\cdot\left(x+1\right)}}$$

Ps.: Remmember that $$\frac{e^a}{e^b}=e^{a-b}$$

Comment: I get: $$\frac{g}{z}=-\text{m}^2$$ But how does that help?

Comment: @Looper: well, it means that $g=-z\cdot e^{-2\ln m}$. So you got $g$ in terms of $z$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the fact that $a\log(b)=\log(b^{a})$ and $e^{\log(b)}=b$.

Comment: Actually, it’s $a\ln(b) = \ln\left( b^a\right)$.